# Problems running an Angular 9 app in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli-v9

I have a working NodeJS server and an Angular 9 app. I'm able to test the app in development mode, it works perfectly.

But, when I build the app with `ng build --prod` and try to access it with NodeJS server I get several errors about file load:

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:8080/styles.09cf2cc3740ba29d305c.css' because its
>   MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and
>   strict MIME checking is enabled.
>
> GET http://localhost:8080/runtime.689ba4fd6cadb82c1ac2.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I have a proxy file in the app to redirect all its petitions to NodeJS:

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please could your give more info: you're using NodeJS for backend API or just to serve static content (your Angular app), or both ?

Comment: I have to say both, I think. I have endpoints for web's querying but I had to put some code for static files like: ```app.use(express.static(config.paths.webs));```. I would like to put the code but it's like a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`proxy.conf.json` aims to provide you an easy way to access to `backend` by rewriting url in development environment, by using `ng serve`.

For example, by accessing `http://localhost:4200/api`, in fact, you access `http://localhost:3000/api`. (so your backend).

But here, you're issue is how to serve Angular files with NodeJS.

Here is a minimal `express` code which serves an `API` endpoint `/api`, and also static files inside `public` sub-directory.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.send({ message: 'api ok' })
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Copy all files generated by `ng build --prod`, (see inside `dist` folder, and `your-app-name` subfolder) to `public` folder.

```sh
node app.js
```

You will be able to access your Angular app at `http://localhost:3000`, and your Angular app will be able to access your API at `http://localhost:3000/api`.